# Has the USA explicitly recognized Israeli sovereignty in West Jerusalem?

Tags: united-states, israel, borders, sovereignty, jerusalem

This is a question about the period of 1948-2017 - up until, but not including, the presidency of Donald Trump.

During this period, had the USA ever officially, explicitly, recognized West Jeruslaem as being Israeli sovereign territory?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but hasn't the UN recognized Israel in the borders of 1967, which includes West Jerusalem? I would not expect an explicit recognization from the USA when it is already recognized by the UN (with, among others, the vote of the USA).

Comment: I agree @Nebr. Isn't West Jerusalem agreed to be Israel and East Jerusalem the one that is not generally recognized as part of Israel?

Comment: @Nebr: 1. US recognition and UN recognition are separate things. 2. There are no "1967 borders"; do you mean the 1949 Rhodes armistice lines? I don't believe the UN had officially recognized those as the legitimate borders of Israel, though I could be wrong. Remember that in the partition plan, Jerusalem is an internationalized territory.

Comment: The armistice lines, also known as the Green Line, are just that - armistice lines, not borders, and are not officially recognized as borders neither by Israel nor by most other states.

Answer (score 3):

Neither before nor during. The president's tweets and press conferences do not constitute a formal recognition. The state department has published a map [U.S. Relations With Israel](https://www.state.gov/p/nea/ci/is/) which says:

> The United States recognized Jerusalem as the capital of Israel in
>   2017 without taking a position on the specific boundaries of Israeli
>   sovereignty.

As such it is rather amorphous and not explicit.

Comment: Actually, it's generally acknowledged that West Jerusalem is part of Israel if I am not mistaken. Your answer is valid for East Jerusalem.

Comment: @Denisdebernardy : Link to such acknowledgement by the US please.

Comment: @einpoklum: See references 2, 3, 4 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Jerusalem - not 100% the US explicitly recognized it, but the point is _West_ Jerusalem's status has little to do with Trump.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: Those references are not to official documents of the United States. So, nothing in the way of explicit formal recognition.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Do you have evidence of that? East Jerusalem is regarded in particular as occupied Palestinian territory. However, this does not imply that Israeli rule over West Jerusalem is internationally recognized.